# Regulation of P2P lending in India

Tags: india, finance, loan

Regarding the legal aspects of peer-to-peer lending in India, I have two questions—

- Whether P2P lending in India is regulated or not?
- If it is regulated then what are the related laws/rules and related agencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What are the related laws/rules and related agencies?**

The Peer to Peer regulations are the *Master Directions - Non-Banking Financial Company - Peer to Peer Lending Platform (Reserve Bank) Directions 2017* [(**pdf**)](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://rbidocs.rbi.org.in/rdocs/notification/PDFs/MDP2PB9A1F7F3BDAC463EAF1EEE48A43F2F6C.PDF&ved=2ahUKEwiCkpGPq_TxAhUkRUEAHfK0BeEQFjAAegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw1dUlEkDy3g7tF9vGNsmo-l) and is regulated by the Reserve Bank of India.

This [Mondaq article](https://www.mondaq.com/india/financial-services/1052480/peer-to-peer-lending-and-its-regulation-in-india-#_ftn1) from last year gives an overview of the above Directions and summarises the compliance requirements.